# How to give nested MongoDb object an ObjectID (Spring Boot)?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDb model called `Location` and another model called `Comments`.

`Comments` is nested inside of `Location`. I would like all `Comments` objects to have an ObjectID, but right now the ObjectID is `null`.

The **Location** model:

```
@Data
public class Location {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    private ArrayList<Comments> comments;

    private String tags;

    public Location() {

    }

    public Location(String name, String latitude, String longitude, ArrayList<Comments> comments, String tags) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public ArrayList<Comments> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(ArrayList<Comments> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

The **Comments** model:

```
@Data
public class Comments {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String text;

    public Comments() {

    }

    public Comments(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

But when I hit my end point here...:

```
    public Location createLocation(Location locDetails) {
        Location location = new Location();
        location.setName(locDetails.getName());
        location.setLatitude(locDetails.getLatitude());
        location.setLongitude(locDetails.getLongitude());
        location.setComments(locDetails.getComments());
        location.setTags(locDetails.getTags());

        return locationRepo.save(location);
    }
```

...then everything gets created successfully in my database, other than the ObjectID for the comments. It is `null` and looks like this:
[image]

So how can I ensure that all `Comments` have an ObjectID?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing annotations that would link the Location document with the Comment document and specify it as a nested schema. Here is a link where you can look learn more about it with examples: [Mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions, **different documents** or the **same document**.

In both solutions, you must use the annotation `@DBRef` in the `Location` class, at the property `comments`.

```java
@Data
public class Location {
    ...
    @DBRef
    private ArrayList<Comments> comments;
    ...
}
```

And the difference between the solutions is in the class `Comments`, if you save the comments in a different document, use the annotation `@Document`, but, if you save it in the same document, use the annotation `@Embedded` (I think, you are trying to do this one).

**Different document:**

```java
@Document
@Data
public class Comments {
...
}
```

**Same document:**

```java
@Embedded
@Data
public class Comments {
...
}
```